# How to fix header cannot sticky in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I already added new feature like sticky header especially in custom theme wordpress on [my development website](http://dev.galerigadget.com/) got unexpected result about navigation cannot sticky after logo like screenshot below:
[image: sticky]

**Here style.css**

```
.site-navigation {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #252525;
    letter-spacing: 0.25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
}

.outer {
    position: relative;
}

.outer .site-navigation {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #252525;
    letter-spacing: 0.25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    top: auto;
}
```

How I can fix it so I can get same result like [this tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/WDnyb/2/)?

**Updated #2:**

I already added javascript and little modified css to my custom theme based on @Saypontigohe suggestion but still not luck.

**Here js code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   window.onscroll = effects;
function effects(){
    var topdis = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) ||  document.body.scrollTop;//distance between top and scroll position
    var scrollHeight = (document.getElementById("action").clientHeight)-200; //height of client scroll, 200 is the amount of pixels from the header


    if(topdis < scrollHeight ){ //if the distance is less than the header height, normal position
        document.getElementById("site-navigation").style.position= "relative";
    }
    else if(topdis >= scrollHeight ){ ///if the distance is more than the header height, fixed position
        document.getElementById("site-navigation").style.position= "fixed";                
    }
}
});
```

**Updated #1:**

Its already fixed based on @iyyappan suggestion and have another problem about how to fix showing sticky header after logo when first time to open website before scrolling like concept below:
[image: main menu]

Comment: Oh.I got it.See my answer below.Please accept and upvote if you found the solution helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this one.**

```
.site-navigation {
    clear: both !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Edit:

```
.site-header {
    background-color: #ff870f;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99 !important;
}
.site-navigation {
    background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    bottom: auto;
    color: #252525;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.25px;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Next to site-navigation apply the below style,

```
<div class="main-content" style="padding-top: 200px;">
```

Comment: thanks. I already updated my style.css based on your suggestion. Please read updated #1 for more information

Answer (score 0):

U need to use javascript for that. You need to know when the header with the logo is out of sight and AFTER that turn the menu on position:fixed

```
window.onscroll = effects;
function effects(){
    var topdis = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) ||  document.body.scrollTop;//distance between top and scroll position
    var scrollHeight = (document.getElementById("action").clientHeight)-200; //height of client scroll, 200 is the amount of pixels from the header


    if(topdis < scrollHeight ){ //if the distance is less than the header height, normal position
        document.getElementById("menu").style.position= "relative";
    }
    else if(topdis >= scrollHeight ){ ///if the distance is more than the header height, fixed position
        document.getElementById("menu").style.position= "fixed";                
    }
}
```

use a plugin or edit the WP templates to put the javascript code in, and change the element id's to the specific element in your theme

Comment: I see you did not change the "action". Try to change that one to the full height of the header (logo and menu). Should work then.

Answer (score 0):

## Sticky Header

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //Enter Your Class or ID
    var $stickyMenu = jQuery('.main-nav');

    var stickyNavTop = jQuery($stickyMenu).offset().top;

    //Get Height of Navbar Div
    var navHeight = jQuery($stickyMenu).height();

    var stickyNav = function(){
        var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
            jQuery($stickyMenu).addClass('sticky');
            jQuery('html').css('padding-top', navHeight + 'px')
        } else {
            jQuery($stickyMenu).removeClass('sticky');
            jQuery('html').css('padding-top', '0')
        }
    };

    stickyNav();

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        stickyNav();
    });
});
```

Just add this section to your footer and add the Menu class.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cybentizen/Lxrn3nkL/

Use the above given jQuery Code with this sticky class properties.

```
.sticky{
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```